# Get Mathematica to Apply Chu-Vandermonde Convolution

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, summation, assumptions

I'd like to get *Mathematica* (11) to do basic sums, such as

```
Sum[Binomial[a, b - k] Binomial[c, d + k], {k, -d, b}].
```

This is the [Chu-Vandermonde sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html),
which equals ${a+c\choose b+d}$, at least for integer $a,c$.

*Mathematica* instead evaluates the sum to

```
Binomial[a, b + d] Hypergeometric2F1[-c, -b - d, 1 + a - b - d, 1],
```

which is true, but not as useful.

My guess was, that I needed to somehow specify that $a,b,c,d$ were positive integers, or something, so I entered the following (BTW, is there an easier way to do this?)

```
$Assumptions =  a ∈ Integers && b ∈ Integers && c ∈ Integers && d ∈ Integers
                && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0
```

An evaluated the sum again, this time with a `FullSimplify`.
However it didn't work, and I still got the hypergeometric representation.

Is this because *Mathematica* doesn't know the formula? Or is there some assumption I didn't tell it? The problem is not just with Vandermonde, but with many similar sums, which I think *Mathematica* should be able to put on a nice closed form, but for some reason it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to the the assumptions that `1 + a > b + d`

```
assume = Element[{a, b, c, d}, Integers] &&
   a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && 1 + a > b + d;

expr = Sum[Binomial[a, b - k] Binomial[c, d + k], {k, -d, b}]

(*  Binomial[a, b + d] Hypergeometric2F1[-c, -b - d, 1 + a - b - d, 1]  *)
```

The additional assumption comes from requiring that the third argument of the `Hypergeometric2F1` be a positive integer.

To eliminate the [`Hypergeometric2F1`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) use [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html)

```
expr2 = Assuming[assume, expr //
    FunctionExpand // FullSimplify]

(*  (a + c)!/((a - b + c - d)! (b + d)!)  *)
```

Verifying that given the assumptions that this is equivalent to the [`Binomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binomial.html)

```
Assuming[assume,
 expr2 == Binomial[a + c, b + d] // FullSimplify]

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT:** Using a replacement rule to simplify

```
rule = (Times[Factorial[x_], Power[Factorial[y_], -1],
       Power[Factorial[z_], -1]] /; z == x-y) :> Binomial[x, z];

expr3=expr2/.rule

(*  Binomial[a+c, b+d]  *)
```

Comment: Thank you! That answered nearly all of my questions, including with regards to the assumption syntax :-)
But why do we require that the third argument is a positive integer? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html only seems to require $1 + a + c > 0$?
Also, I assume there is no way to make Mathematica take the last step of reassembling the binomial?

Comment: @ThomasAhle - since you assumed that all variables are integers then `1+a-b-d` is an integer. If it is not a positive integer then there will be a discontinuity unless either  `c` or `b+d` has a smaller magnitude than the magnitude of `1+a-b-d`. Rather than work out all the details I simplified the problem to `1 + a > b + d`. To rewrite as a `Binomial` you would need to `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` with a custom [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

Comment: @Thomas, recall the definition of the Gaussian hypergeometric function, whose series at $0$ includes a Pochhammer symbol in the denominator. Since $(-j)_k=0,\,k>j>0$, hypergeometric functions do not admit these numbers as "denominator parameters".